# MCE chunk size when reading from STDIN

Tags: perl, multicore

I'm writing a Perl program that processes a high number of log entries. To speed things up I'm using [MCE](https://metacpan.org/pod/MCE) to create a number of worker processes to handle processing in parallel. So far things are great, but I've found myself trying different chunk sizes in a very unscientific manner. Here's some background before I get to my question.

We're receiving logs from a number of syslog sources and collecting them at a central location. The central syslog server writes these log entries to a single text file. The program in question picks up the logs from this text file, does some munging, and ships them elsewhere. The raw log files are then archived.

To read the log files I'm doing this:

```
my $tail = 'tail -q -F '.$logdir.$logFile;
open my $tail_fh, "-|", $tail or die "Can't open tail\n";
```

I'm then using mce_loop_f to iterate over the file handle:

```
mce_loop_f { my $hr = process($_); MCE->gather($hr); } $tail_fh;
```

This works well for the most part, but if there is a spike in log activity the program starts to get bogged down. While there are a number of factors to make things "go faster" one of those factors I'm a little unsure of is chunk_size in MCE.

I understand that chunk_size has an "auto" value, but how would that work on a file handle that is a pipe from tail? Would auto be appropriate here?

What factors should I consider when adjusting the chunk_size? Log entries occur at a rate of 1000-2000 events per second depending on time of day (1000 at night, 2000 during the day).

I'm also a neophyte when it comes to MCE, so if mce_loop_f is a bad idea for this use case, please let me know.

Comment: You'll need to benchmark

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the MCE distribution. Some of them contain the `chunk_size` in comments and code. Have you looked there?

Comment: @ikegami I did some benchmarking, but I'm a little unsure what to make of the results. I took a sample of log files (~300,000 entries) and just timed them using the different chunk sizes. A chunk size of 1 completes in 39s while a chunk size of 'auto' takes 49s. This is the opposite of what I was expecting. Does this mean there's something else in my code that's a bottle neck or are there conditions where a chunk size of 1 is appropriate?

Comment: @simbabque Thanks I did look at some of those examples, but given what I just saw in my benchmark I only have more questions. Is a chunk size of 1 perfectly normal for certain applications? The examples and documentation suggest it, but I'm not sure under what conditions that is applicable.

Comment: I think you are best off asking the author. In general CPAN authors are normal people that are very approachable. They will usually be happy to hear about your use case of their module and provide help with it, especially if it's not a standard thing. For those, IRC is the place to go if you want to talk to the behind the scenes people. If you are unsure about that I recommend SawyerX's YAPC keynote [_The joy in what we do_](https://youtu.be/M-VKSCgIgo0)

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the advice, I might do that. I'll watch the keynote over lunch, sounds interesting (the "I'm going to swear" intro was great haha).

Comment: @Sgt B. That is an interesting use case. The chunk_size is hard-coded to 245_760 (240k) for STDIN when 'auto' is specified. A chunk size value of 8192 or lower means the number of lines to read. A value higher than 8192 means the number of bytes to read. MCE automatically reads till the end of the line before passing to the worker. I'm going to do some testing and report back. Perhaps, the default 240k for STDIN ('auto' setting) is too high.

Comment: Am not sure what the OP process is doing. Therefore, is not easy to replicate. A possible reason for a chunk_size value of 1 completing sooner is due to delays from tail. Although, 1000 ~ 2000 events per second is a lot to the observer, there are likely many micro-seconds in between each event. Basically, tiny pauses by tail itself. With that said, try 100 (lines) for chunk_size or '10k' (bytes).

Comment: There is also the max_workers option. Specifying 'auto' (the default for MCE Models) will not go higher than 8. Try max_workers => MCE::Util::get_ncpu or specify the desired number of workers when running on a box with more than 8 logical cores. Leaving some reserves for for other processes may be beneficial.

Comment: In my testing, tail is the bottleneck. Thus, a chunk size greater than 1 did not help for the tail pipe test. I compared the unix tail with cat and reading the pipe in Perl. Chunking enabled faster reading for the cat pipe test. But, not for tail.

Comment: @user1810910 Thanks for that feedback and testing and indeed it appears that tail is the bottleneck. When I test on a file I get significant increases when chunking which is expected. With a pipe from tail, no increases. The program itself is designed to monitor logs so the pipe from tail is required. I ended up leaving chunk to auto as the program itself inserts records in bulk and the 240k default chunk size works well. I might play with that a bit, but overall it's doing its job. Again thanks for the testing, it's nice to know *why* I was getting the results I was.

Comment: It has been a while since I've logged into SO and glad to read the outcome. I edited my profile which is @user1810910. Cheers.